# How to swap 2 macros in c++?

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor

I have a project to do from university and this projects asks us to create a new pseudo language using macros with preprocessor.

There is one command though that i just can't find a way to make it work.

The command goes like this,

```
DAMAGE DEFENDER 12
```

I have tried multiple things and as I mention to the title, if it is possible to swap the Macros somehow it could solve my problem.

DEFENDER  = Player[1-turn] which is an Object of a Player Class and turn goes from 0 to 1,

I tried implementing a function using DAMAGE but it's not possible because there is no comma within DEFENDER and the number, plus I couldn't close the parenthesis after 12.

I tried with operator overloading and it seems like it could work, only if the swap is possible.
I was thinking of making the DAMAGE macro a minus (-) and do something like that

```
Player[1-turn] - 12
```

Maybe something else, like using a MACRO on condition?

E.g. `#define DEFENDER Player[1-turn] CONDITION_MACRO`

```
#define CONDITION_MACRO -/+ (for damage or heal)
```

But the DAMAGE comes first as a keyword. Also the DEFENDER macro is used in other macros like GET_HP(DEFENDER) so it is useful to stay like that, but if you have any ideas that could solve the issue for both cases i would be very grateful.

Comment: It's unclear what are you asking, ie. what is "DAMAGE DEFENDER"? to get better response you should post problematic code.

Comment: What you need is more macro functions, ie. one called `ATTACK(_VA_ARGS__)` which will call DAMAGE and DEFENDER in any order you want. if there are variable arguments you want to supply you will need macro function overloading.

Comment: This is really not something that `#define` is good at. You're missing a ton of syntax here. `DAMAGE(DEFENDER, 12))` would be way easier to implement.

Comment: @tadman That's true, unluckily i can't impement it like that.

Comment: I don't know how you'd do this without a little bit of C++ syntax in it to make it compile. `DAMAGE DEFENDER 12;` would be a step up. Short of `#define 12 12;` I just don't know.